# Why can't I connect to a local server using phantomjs / casperjs

Tags: localhost, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to just establish a connection to a running server at localhost:3000 by opening / starting a connection to http://127.0.0.1:3000. I'm wondering why this isn't working? I thought the script is being run on my computer/browser so it should be able to connect to anything that I can connect to via browser?

Comment: Can you give us some more code? (:

Comment: Never mind I resolved it. Was trying to connect a virtual machine to a server running on my actual comp. :P (different localhosts)

Comment: Then answer your own question (: Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: Was trying to connect a virtual machine to a server running on my computer's local port (different localhosts)